# Scopes being ignored by Azure AD with React Native integration

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm creating an app that login with Azure AD and the same token returned by Azure AD should be used to consume API's.
I've followed all the steps describe [at this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) with success and it's working.
My problem is about generate the access-token and refresh-token with a custom scope that allows the app to call the api.
I've tried to react-native libraries and each one has a different problem (probably my code has a problem, not the libraries).

First I've tried [react-native-azure-auth](https://github.com/vmurin/react-native-azure-auth) and when I've defined the following scope:

```
scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'User.Read', 'offline_access', 'api://multiplan_broker_dev/read']
```

When defining this scope, it returns a token only valid for the scope api://multiplan_broker_dev/read and doesn't return a refresh_token (seems it's ignoring the offline_access scope)

You can see the whole returned object [here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/XRv4bxlG) and the main code for this implementation [here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/qa0NxkOE)

The main piece of code is below:

```
const CLIENT_ID = '75a43463-c3b4-4e31-b740-3a5a1858XXXX';
const TENANT_ID = '862085e1-045e-4d8c-832f-96837b0XXXXX';

const azureAuth = new AzureAuth({
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  tenant: TENANT_ID,
});

export default class Auth0Sample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { accessToken: null, user: '' , mails: [], userId: ''};
  }

  _onLogin = async () => {
    try {
      let tokens = await azureAuth.webAuth.authorize({
        scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'User.Read', 'offline_access', 'api://multiplan_broker_dev/read'],
        login_hint: 'rioa@XXX.com' 
      })

      console.log('CRED>>>', tokens)
      this.setState({ accessToken: tokens.accessToken });
      let info = await azureAuth.auth.msGraphRequest({token: tokens.accessToken, path: 'me'})
      console.log('info', info)
      this.setState({ user: info.displayName, userId: tokens.userId })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error during Azure operation', JSON.stringify(error))
    }
  };
```

So I've tried to another library ([react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth)) and it returns the refresh_token, but ignores completely the scopes I'm asking for.

You can see the returned object [here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/A2QERo25) and main code [here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/Y746dJ2k)

What I'm doing wrong?
P.S: The solution can be for any library, I don't have preference.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope is not correct. Your scope contains both Microsoft Graph API endpint and your own api endpoint. As far as I know we can only ask for the token for one resource at one time.

You can change the scope as below:

```
scope: ['openid', 'offline_access', 'api://multiplan_broker_dev/read']
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. It's not possible to ask for an access_token for multiple application in the same request. I still don't know why the first example is never returning the refresh_token, but the second example and I can solve my problem asking for different tokens.